# Can Spectra find eigenvectors and eigenvalues of complex-valued matrices?

Tags: c++, eigensystem, eigen

I am using [Spectra](https://spectralib.org/) to iteratively solve large-scale eigenvalue problems. I like it because it readily works on windows, and is header-only. I would like to know if it supports complex-valued matrices. [Here is a list of eigensolvers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ESR3uucNvVKEoIcalP9gR7ApaOElLwmE5sAS-VRMOM/edit#gid=90156307) that lists Spectra and says it supports both real and complex problems. But the API Documentation implies otherwise. If it doesn't is there any library similar to Spectra that does (i.e. header-only, Windows-friendly, commercial-friendly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projects discussion page for future features (link below, see item #3) suggests there's no support for complex numbers. I don't think I'd hold my breath for this .. that link is from 2020, subsequent filed issues indicate that there was still no support by 2022 either.

https://github.com/yixuan/spectra/issues/92